# Unable to see build step while configuring a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins and also installed the necessary plugins needed for pipeline and restarted jenkins.
I created a new pipeline. When I click on configure, "build" step is not visible.

[image]
Image of the steps visible when I click on configure.

"Pipeline: Build Step" plugin is installed. Ideally this should be enough for "build" step to show up. 
Can somebody let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: are you referring to the build section tab. Pipeline jobs in Jenkins do not contain the build section. Create a Jenkins “freestyle” job to view build section.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I created a free style job and I am able to see the build section tab.